# Overflowing a larger container within a smaller one and centering it

Tags: html, css

Basically, I am looking for a way to center a container that is 1600px within a container that is 940px.

I want the page to stay centered at all times, and the main content of the site is 940px wide. I have an image that is 1600px, and just adding the image forces the image to align left with the 940px container and overflow to the right 660px. See the image below for an example.

[image: example #1]

What I want is the image to center within the 940px container, and save for adding multiple background images, which really isn't pre IE8 friendly, I am at a loss.

I've never really had to do this before, so I've never run into this problem.

Right now, I have the page set to a master container of 1600px. This works, but when you open the page, the page starts at the far left of the 1600px container and the main content appears uncentered.

Example 2 below is what I am looking for.

[image: example #2]

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks guys and gals!

Comment: I don't understand why you just don't set the 1600px image to the background of the body.

Comment: yes, you could do that and just set a padding on the left and right of the main content. depends on what the OP wants to accomplish though.

Comment: I should have mentioned that there already is a background image. It stretches at 100%, and short of using CSS3 Mulitple background images, which I don't believe works before ie8, I was thinking this would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you could just center the 1600 container relative to the Page using the following attributes:

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -800px;
```

Comment: Would this push the page to the right on page load though? I want the main content in the 940px container to be centered. I'll try it and let you know, thanks for the answer!

Comment: This worked. I had to use this since my image was a background image, and not of the img src family. So you get the checkmark :) Thanks bro.

I didn't set the page to left: 50% but I moved the margin left 330px and that worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a negative margin on the image.  You can use Javascript to compute the actual number, but if it's always going to be 1600 within 940, then you can set a negative margin of 330px.

(Container width - Content width) / 2 = Left Margin

```
#container img { margin-left:  -330px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to get the width of both divs, then take the difference between the two (1600-940=660px). Divide that by two for centering (330px). Then position the container left that amount (-330px).